# A quale accezione si riferisce il verbo "annotare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Danubio*, di Claudio Magris, ho letto:

> In una splendida pagina, il 18 marzo 1936, egli **annota** una conversazione fra Gorki e Malraux, giunto in visita nell'URSS. È un'instantanea fulminante dell'ottusità, dalla quale nessuno è al riparo.

Poi l'autore spiega la conversazione.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/annotare) ho trovato che il verbo "annotare" può avere queste accezioni:

> **1.** Segnare, registrare una cosa, prenderne nota: *a. un fatto importante; a. una data nel taccuino; a. diligentemente le spese; a. a credito*, accreditare. **2.** Corredare di note, postillare, commentare: *a. un poema, una raccolta di leggi*.

Tuttavia, non riesco a capire a quale di queste due accezioni corrisponda il verbo "annotare" usato nel passaggio precedente. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Comment: Credo che serva più contesto. Chi è *egli*? che relazione ha con Gorki e Malraux?

Comment: @DenisNardin: "Egli" è lo scrittore [Ervin Sinkó](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ervin_%C5%A0inko). Magris spiega che questo autore è andato esule a Mosca e immagino che in quei tempi abbia saputo di questa conversazione tra Gorki e Malraux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credo che l'accezione più probabile sia la prima (registrare). La seconda (corredare di note, commentare) non mi sembra adeguata perché nel brano citato si parla di «pagina» e di «istantanea fulminante», che danno l'idea di qualcosa di breve e sintetico.

Answer (score 1):

L'accezione che si adatta al passaggio da te indicato è la prima, anche se si potrebbe utilizzare (oltre a segnare, registrare una cosa, prenderne nota) la parola ***riporta*** al posto di annota.

Da [Treccani per riportare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riportare/) (significato 2b.)

> b. Di discorsi, notizie, passi di libri, ecc., farli conoscere,
> comunicarli ad altri a voce o per scritto, citarli

Infatti l'autore, tramite una testimonianza di chi era presente a quell'evento, spiega poi il contenuto della conversazione.